# Unable to run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in live environment: "processer context corrupt"

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-environment

When I try to boot Ubuntu 14.04 live CD or live 8GB USB made with unetbootin, whether 32-bit or 64-bit, I get these error messages:

[image: Error Message]

My computer specifications are:

- HDD: 80GB IDE and 80GB SATA
- Motherboard: ASUS P5VD2-MX SE
- PSU: 480W
- RAM: DDR2 2GB
- Processor: Intel Pentium E2140 1.6 Ghz
- Graphic Card: NVIDIA GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS

I want to try Ubuntu before installing it to this computer.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What hardware are you using (make + model etc) - the second screenshot doesn't actually give much on that.

Comment: My Hardware is:

HDD: 80GB IDE and 80GB SATA
Motherboard: ASUS P5VD2-MX SE
PSU: 480W
RAM: DDR2 2GB
Processor: Intel Pentium E2140 1.6 Ghz
Graphic Card: NVIDIA GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS

Comment: did you have any errors with freezing on the previous OS? This really seems to be pointing to some sort of processor failure

Comment: Nope, all previous OS (Such Windows any version) has no problem.

Answer (score 1):

That definitely looks like a hardware issue, and is somewhat unrelated to Linux. As your machine looks to be several years old, it could most likely be a problem with the power supply or the mainboard (capacitors are prone to fail after a while). If you have a spare power supply, I would recommend you try replacing your power supply with that.

It might also be related to the memory, or the BIOS. In [How to diagnose and fix Kernel Panic Fatal Machine Check error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221328/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-kernel-panic-fatal-machine-check-error), the problem was fixed by switching the BIOS boot mode to **UEFI OS** from **UEFI and CSM OS**. I would try that suggestion first.